# Chrome continually loading from appcache

Tags: html, html5-appcache

I can't stop Chrome from loading resources from the cache manifest. I changed my markup so

the page begins with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="fouc">
<head>
```

I grabbed this markup after I dumped Chrome's appcache manually and I viewed source.

However, Chrome's console has:

```
Document was loaded from Application Cache with manifest http://localhost:47932/Manifest/Index localhost/:1
Application Cache Checking event localhost/:1
Application Cache NoUpdate event
```

How do I turn appcache off once I've turned it on?!

I should mention that I edited my cache manifest. It now reads:

```
CACHE MANIFEST

#Version 107

NETWORK:
*

CACHE:
```

I have removed every entry from the Cache section, and Chrome still refers to the cache manifest.

Answer (score 4):

The HTML page specifying the manifest is itself implicitly cached, so the browser won't "see" your update to the HTML unless you update the manifest as well (or delete it). Did you make a change to the application cache manifest after changing the HTML? The byte content of the manifest must change to trigger the browser to check for updated versions of any cached resources.

If all else fails, you can clear Chrome's application cache manually by visiting `chrome://appcache-internals/`

Answer (score 1):

Remove your manifest file from the server. Or just rename it.

Comment: I'm loath to have to go to clear chrome's application cache manually, renaming the manifest was eventually the only way I could get the page to reload, without clearing the cache. Just changing a few comment bytes in the manifest used to work, then at some point it just stopped.